# 404 error handling with htaccess and css

Tags: html, css, error-handling, http-status-code-404

hello  i have a problem with my 404 error handling.

i added to htaccess:

> ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

so in case of typing something like:

> www.domain.com/abc

everything works fine with my php page. the problem will be when typing something like:

> www.domain.com/abc/

means adding a slash to the url the 404 error page appears but doesn*t load the css file?

if there is someone who could tell me whats going wrong over here, i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Comment: Not an explanation for your problem I know, but if you need a quick fix you could put the css in the html

Comment: You need to show how your HTML for 404 page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the 404 page will be displayed from any URL, you will need to use absolute paths for any external page assets like CSS files, images, JavaScript files, etc.

So any relative paths...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="site.css" />
```

will need to be changed to absolute paths...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/site.css" />
```

Comment: hello and thank you very much for your help. thats exactly why it wont work.