# trailing slash results in 404 error page CSS not working

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404

I'm new to this, so please be don't have a go at me.

I have redesigned a website. I've set up a 404 error page so that visitors with bookmarks to now non-existent pages or pages whos names have changed can still navigate to the new pages.

For example if someone tries to visit a now non-existent page www.xyz.co.uk/nonsense they will get a nice looking 404 page that looks consistent with the rest of the site.

However, if someone adds a trailing slash www.xyz.co.uk/nonsence/ then the CSS on the 404 page doesn't work. There is no styling.

How do I get the CSS on the 404 page to work when someone uses a trailing slash?

Please note I don't want to create a htaccess file adding trailing slashes. There are several reasons for this which I can't explain here. I just want the 404 page CSS to work.

UPDATE
I've changed the link to my CSS file so that it is absolute. The CSS now works, but the logo image is now missing (from the 404 page when someone uses a trailing slash). So presumably I need to use absolute links to images and CSS on my 404 page?

UPDATE 2
After further seaching I think I've found the answer here [404 error handling with htaccess and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734654/404-error-handling-with-htaccess-and-css)

Comment: use absolute links with your images in css too!

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute links to the CSS, images and other resources